# Como Ocupar una caja con una mitad en imagen y la otra en texto

Tags: css

Estoy practicando `CSS`y estoy creando unos cards, pero me encuentro con un problema el cual no he podido solucionar y es hacer que en un card valla la mitad una imagen y la otra mitad sea texto, use el width:50% el los distintos clases que componen al card, pero al hacer esto la mitad del texto se desborda.

Este es mi código:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 4px gray;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}

.card-img {
  width: 50%;
}

.card-img>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.6rem;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.card-content {
  width: 50%;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="capablanca.jpg" alt="capablanca">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="content-date">
      <div class="card-content__title"></div>
      <div class="card-content__date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content__content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis voluptatum quasi corrupti aliquam delectus perferendis et ea asperiores, neque quam alias aut totam aperiam quod accusantium mollitia, reprehenderit hic omnis.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el resultado:  
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quisieras que el texto que se desborda no se vea, ¿cierto?

Comment: si quisiera que el texto no se mostrara pero no he podido dar con una solucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar que el texto que se desborda se vea, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Mover el alto aplicado a la imagen (`eg: height: 8.6rem;`) al `.card`
- Aplicar `overflow: hidden` al `.card-content`.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 4px gray;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 8.6rem; /*ACA*/
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}

.card-img {
  width: 50%;
}

.card-img>img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.card-content {
  width: 50%;
  color: gray;
  overflow: hidden; /*ACA*/
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px"><!-- ELIMINAR / Agregado para el ejemplo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="capablanca.jpg" alt="capablanca">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content-date">
        <div class="card-content__title"></div>
        <div class="card-content__date"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content__content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis voluptatum quasi corrupti aliquam delectus perferendis et ea asperiores, neque quam alias aut totam aperiam quod accusantium mollitia, reprehenderit hic omnis.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era lo que estaba buscando